# Adding extra field to UserModel Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, model

So I finally managed to add a location field to my User model and this is the code I have:

model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        location = models.CharField(('location'),max_length=30, blank=False)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

and admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django import forms
from UserProfile.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import *

class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    username = forms.RegexField(label=("Username"), max_length=30, regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$', help_text = ("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only."),error_messages = {'invalid': ("This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.")})
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=("Password confirmation"), widget=forms.PasswordInput, help_text = ("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))
    email = forms.EmailField(label=("Email address"))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username",)

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(("A user with that username already exists."))

    def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    if email == "":
            raise forms.ValidationError((""))
    return email

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1", "")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data["password2"]
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(("The two password fields didn't match."))
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    username = forms.RegexField(label=("Username"), max_length=30, regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
        help_text = ("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only."),
        error_messages = {'invalid': ("This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.")})
    location = forms.CharField(label=("Location"),max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        f = self.fields.get('user_permissions', None)
        if f is not None:
            f.queryset = f.queryset.select_related('content_type')

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'location')}),
        (('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'user_permissions')}),
        (('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
        (('Groups'), {'fields': ('groups',)}),
    )
    #list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'location')
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm
    form = MyUserChangeForm

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

When I tried creating a user it finally didn't error. But when I went to edit the information about the user, the location field was empty. I checked the database manually using sqlite database browser. And I assumed by creating a UserProfile would add extra tables to the database, but it didn't. What I want is for the location field to be trated just like the email field or the username or any other information stored about the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't add fields to the old model this way, you're creating a new one that's associated with it. Your data will be in `app_userprofile` table, and you can access that instance (to save that location or whatever) via `user.get_profile()`. You can't use straightforward `ModelForm` for that, I'm afraid, you need to handle the profile yourself.

Comment: oh ok! I see it now. I am looking in the UserProfile table now and for some reason it didn't save the information field for location. could you advice me or link me something that could help me write to the database the location to the user id and then call it back to be displayed?